# PYTHONPATH environment variable

Tags: python, environment-variables

I have this in my `~/.profile`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/dev/python-files
```

In the `python-files` directory, I have a few projects cloned from git-hub (flask, curveship and py-vgdl).

Whenever I try to start up any of the examples in these projects, I get errors similar to the following:

```
$ python ~/python-files/py-vgdl/examples/gridphysics/frogs.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/dev/python-files/py-vgdl/examples/gridphysics/frogs.py", line 67, in <module>
        from vgdl.core import VGDLParser
ImportError: No module named vgdl.core
```

It seems to me that I shouldn't get this error because I have that `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable set up?

Running the python interactive interpreter:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ["PYTHONPATH"]
'/home/dev/python-files'
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try appending to PYTHONPATH instead of overwriting it completely.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/dev/python-files
```

References:

According to the the [Python documentation on PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables)

> Augment the default search path for module files. [...]
>
> The default search path is installation dependent, but generally begins with `prefix/lib/pythonversion` (see `PYTHONHOME` above). It is *always* appended to `PYTHONPATH`.

meaning that some values exist in `PYTHONPATH` and the default search path is also only appended.

Additionally, [this blog post](http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath) ([Archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20141113112849/http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath)) also explains clearly why you need to append to `PYTHONPATH` and not overwrite it. Scrolling down to the section - *Special cases and examining the search path* explains it clearly (unfortunately no relative URL to that link so you'll have to scroll). Although the user gives the examples on a mac they are very much relevant to any platform

Comment: @Garrett Thanks :) Updated with Archive.org link.

Comment: +1 for the archive / stereoplex link. It answers so many questions it should be on the front page of the official Python docs!

Comment: See https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2020/08/never-run-python-in-your-downloads-folder.html

Answer (score 10):

You can also do as follows:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)
```

or

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PWD}
```

`pwd` is the present working directory.

Comment: Beware, this will overwrite your PYTHONPATH in the process! If you want to add pwd to your PYTHONPATH: `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$(pwd)`

Answer (score 5):

`PYTHONPATH` should point to where your Python packages and modules are, not where your checkouts are. In other words, if you do an `ls "$PYTHONPATH"` you should see `*.py` files (*Python modules*) and directories containing `__init__.py` files (*Python packages*).

So, if you want to be able to `import vgdl`, your `PYTHONPATH` should look like this:

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/dev/python-files/py-vgdl
```

because the `vgdl` *package* is inside `py-vgdl`, not inside `python-files`.

To add the other paths too, you can use `:` to separate them:

```
PYTHONPATH="/home/dev/python-files/py-vgdl:/home/dev/python-files/something:$PYTHONPATH"
```

This will indeed work, however, for such cases, using `PYTHONPATH` may be too complex. What I recommend is to use [`virtualenv`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/python-virtualenv), which is made on purpose to simplify situations like yours. What you have to do is basically:

1. Create an environment: `virtualenv env`
2. 'Activate' it: `source env/bin/activate`
3. Install your packages: this could be done either using `pip` or the `setup.py` script of your packages.
4. Enjoy.

I'm not giving much information because virtualenv is [well-documented](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and if you need help with something, you'd better open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo 'export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/caff-dir/python'
```

Also, you may need to run following:

```
pip install -r requirement.txt
```